# Installing and running Capybara on Rails 3 (uninitialized constant Object::Rack (NameError))

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, integration-testing, capybara

I'm trying to follow the instructions [here](http://techiferous.com/2010/04/using-capybara-in-rails-3/) to install Capybara. But each time I try to run the integration test,  I get:

```
/Users/rambo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/bundler/gems/capybara-6641fddcfc33/lib/capybara/rails.rb:4:in `<top (required)>': uninitialized constant Object::Rack (NameError)
    from /Users/rambo/Code/ror/witsvale_app/test/integration_test_helper.rb:1:in `require'
    from /Users/rambo/Code/ror/witsvale_app/test/integration_test_helper.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from test/integration/capy_test.rb:1:in `require'
    from test/integration/capy_test.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/rambo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@global/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake/rake_test_loader.rb:5:in `load'
```

The line that is causing the problem is `require capybara/rails`.

Any ideas will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I was going to say something silly like "You have to spell out rambo. It needs to be Rambo, John J."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I feel like a dum dum.

Anyway, I've solved it. Turns out I was missing 'test_helper.rb' in the 'test' folder. After including that, it works!